# Select recond by max date return latest record

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

In PostgreSQL database i have a table that have 2x records with the same foreign key but the date/time is different, i want todo a select in a LEFT JOIN sub-query to return only the max record (the latest one). The ON clause will then be for the foreign key.

```
Foreign Key | date_created
1           | 2017-11-24 17:22:01
1           | 2017-11-23 17:32:20
```

I want the latest record being the one for 2017-11-23 17:32:20

What I tried:

```
SELECT sa.foreign_key, max(date_created) as date_created
FROM table sa
GROUP BY sa.foreign_key, sa.date_created
```

It still return both records and not the very latest one only.

Comment: Rmove the `sa.date_created` from the `group by` and thats it.

Comment: "Foreign key" is a very poor choice of column name.

Comment: @jarih for copyright reasons i off course didn't include the names of my real tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sa.foreign_key 
                        ORDER BY sa.date_created DESC) AS rn
      FROM table sa) sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```